# Would this PHP inserting be secure?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

I've been working on a little script to insert data into a database but I'm not very sure if it's secure this way. Some feedback would be pretty cool! So my question, is this a secure way of inserting data?

CODE:

```
function dbRowInsert($table, $data) {
   require_once('../config.inc.php');

     $buildData = null;
     $countLoop = 1;

     foreach($data as $field) {
          $sep = ($countLoop!=count($data) ? ',' : '') ;
      if((int)$field == $field) {
        $buildData .= (int)$field . $sep;
      } else {
        $buildData .= '"' .mysqli_real_escape_string((string)$field) . '"' . $sep;
      }
      $countLoop++;
     }

   $fields = array_keys($data);

   mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO" . $table . "(`" . implode('`, `', $fields) . "`)
                        VALUES('" . $buildData . "')");
}
```

Comment: If your table / column names are not white-listed this is insecure.

Comment: Try code review also http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JayBlanchard Can I ask you, why this is insecure? If that's not off-topic.

Comment: Because any table or column name could be used for the query.

Comment: btw, `mysqli_real_escape_string` requires db connection be passed. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh yeah, didn't see that one yet! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use object-oriented style. That's the first. The second is to use methods

```
prepare(), bind(), execute()
```

instead of

```
mysqli_real_escape_string()
```

etc.

Read about it in manual, it's simple and you will find it very useful and safety.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: I'll have a look at this, thanks!